# Opening a program and loading a file into the program

Tags: database, powershell, sqlite, sqlite-browser

I am looking for a way to create a Powershell script that will allow me to open DB Browser for SQLite `("C:\Program Files\DB Browser for SQLite\DB Browser for SQLite.exe")` and upon opening, load a file `(C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\AirHauler2XP\Company\Atlas Airlines25045 PM.db)` in order for me to edit.  Any help would be great (if possible).

Comment: can you do that in a cmd console? if so, that same thing otta work in a PoSh console.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documentation: https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/wiki/Command-Line-Interface#examples

According to that, it should be:

```
"C:\Program Files\DB Browser for SQLite\sqlitebrowser" "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\AirHauler2XP\Company\Atlas Airlines25045 PM.db"
```

Answer (score 0):

@ChristianBaumann is OK, and it will work from command prompt. But for powershell this will fail. You need to use `&` to run it:

```
& "C:\Program Files\DB Browser for SQLite\sqlitebrowser.exe" "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\AirHauler2XP\Company\Atlas Airlines25045 PM.db"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add it to the path one way or another.

```
$env:path += ';C:\Program Files\DB Browser for SQLite'
cd AppData\Roaming\AirHauler2XP\Company
sqlitebrowser '.\Atlas Airlines25045 PM.db'   # tab completion on the filename
```